# What is the correct term for relative number of edges in a graph?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

If $G = (V, E)$ is a [simple graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SimpleGraph.html), what is the name of the quantity

$$\frac{|E|}{\binom{|V|}{2}} = \frac{\text{number of edges}}{\text{maximal number of edges}}\;\text{?}$$

Comment: According to [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_graph), this might be referred as the graph density.

Comment: @Zubzub Shame on me, did not click on that when I was googling.

Comment: I would call it _edge density_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Zubzub commented, this is the *graph density*.